# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' Android

Tags: android

Error when importing the project via git .I tried importing the project via git and executed the project and it gives me this error:

```
 com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

main:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.ocpsoft:ocpsoft-pretty-time:1.0.6'
    compile project(':facebook2')
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.0.5'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
```

horizontal:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
}
```

facebook:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22)'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see where you have:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

You are actually compiling all of Google's play services and that will often result in a mulidex error, meaning you have a whole lot of modules and code. It is best to only compile the API you need, for instance, if you want to use play service's location API just compile it this way:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

Comment: Awesome .Why does that happen ? I thought play-services will take care of conflict internally.Kindly explain.Thanks.

Comment: I experienced this a while back too, and I was as confused. I read from some developer site that play-services is a huge library, it contains all google APIs such Google Maps, Cloud Messaging, Wear, etc... so you can imagine how big it is. So when you compile play-services as whole, it will compile all those APIs too, even the ones you are not gonna use, so always tell play-services which API you want to use.